# Oracle 11gr2 error creating stored procedure with isolation level

Tags: oracle, plsql

I was used to MySql syntax, but now I'm trying to study Oracle.
Let's take a look at the following stored procedure(using SQL Developer):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myPROC(aux OUT NUMBER,
    par1 IN  VARCHAR2, par2 IN VARCHAR2)
    AS
    BEGIN
   COMMIT;
   SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; 
   --OR READ COMMITTED(any, does not matter)
  END myPROC;
```

I've read official documentation but I still cannot figure how to set isolation level for a stored procedure transaction or session.
This code is compiled but with errors. How can something be successfully compiled, BUT with errors.

I have used show errors but still not very useful hints...
Any advice? I have to mention that it's somehow pointing to the set transaction line...

Comment: when mouse over set transaction... is says Syntax error expecting "("

Comment: compiled fine for me.  If you have questions about isolation levels - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2010/10-jan/o65asktom-082389.html

Comment: it says compiled fine. but if compile it several times, or you place the mouse cursor over the set transaction... it will give error. If I comment the COMMIT stmt it works.

Comment: You said it compiled with errors, but didn't show the output from `show errors`; but then you said it compiled OK. Which is is? And which version of SQL Developer - maybe it's an older one that doesn't recognise `set` in that context?

Comment: I am using 4.0.3. Seems that without _COMMIT;_ it compiles. I believe it is okay now...